# Data types where precision level means range of tolerance

Tags: language-agnostic, types, comparison, intervals

What existing terminology and art is there for **data types that have values implying ranges of tolerance**, not specific points?

An example: time values. In ISO 8601 notation, the value `1964` encompasses the values `1964-05`, `1964-05-02`, `1964-05-02T18`, `1964-05-02T18:27`, `1964-05-02T18:27:43`, `1964-05-02T18:27:43.0613`.

That is, each one of those values is not a zero-dimensional point, but an *interval* encompassing a range of more-precise values.

The more precise values in that set should compare equal to the less-precise ones:

```
1964 < 1964-05-02 → False
1964 > 1964-05-02 → False
1964 = 1964-05-02 → True
```

and ‘greater than’ and ‘less than’ should be both false for values encompassed within a less-precise value. The intervals don't overlap, so that's not a concern.

```
1964-05-02T18:27:43 < 1964-05-02T18:30:11 → True
1964-05-02T18:27:43 < 1964-05-02 → False
1964-05-02T18:27:43 < 1964-05-04 → True
```

But how should such types be implemented? What kind of comparison am I talking about? What about arithmetic on such values?

In short, what existing body of knowledge should I be looking to for exploration of these concepts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your italics managed to work out, this is called [interval arithmetic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_arithmetic).

You're specifically interested in order and equality relationships between interval values. The wikipedia article doesn't talk about that, but i assume it has been worked on, as it's a fairly basic thing to want to do with numbers, even fuzzy ones.

I would imagine that you would say that two intervals are *not equal* if their ranges do not overlap at all, and that an interval is *greater than* another interval if the former's range lies entirely above the latter's.

However, i don't think you can have a sensible definition of *equal*; you might need several different kinds of quasi-equality. You could say two ranges which are not *not equal* are *equal*, but i don't think that really helps. That's more like *possibly equal*. Then there's your idea of one range containing another, in which case you might say that the larger was *roughly equal* to the smaller. However, since the *roughly equal* relationship is not symmetric, it's not an [equivalence relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation), and so it doesn't make a good kind of general-purpose equality.

Or maybe this whole thing is just a generalised case of the idea of [significant figures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures)? I suppose interval arithmetic is just the arithmetic you use to deal with numbers that have significant figures.